# Separate punctuation marks in C from a word

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to separate all words from a text and I need to separate the punctuation marks too.

What's the best way to separate them and save it on a string array?

Here's an exemple:

1. **input**:

   - "Hi, my name is Sara!"
2. **expected output**

   - "Hi"
   - ","
   - "my"
   - "name"
   - "is"
   - "Sara"
   - "!"
3. **actual output**

   - "Hi,"
   - "my"
   - "name"
   - "is"
   - "Sara!"

**My Code:**

```
palavra_linha[i] = strtok (linhas[i], " \n\r");

while (palavra_linha[i] != NULL) {
    palavras_finais[j] = palavra_linha[i];
    j++;
    palavra_linha[i] = strtok (NULL, " \n\r");
}
```

I know that I have to use something like that, but it's not working, the condicion is assumed as false:

```
if (strlen(palavra_linha[i])-1) == '.') {
    palavras_finais[j] = palavra_linha[i];
}
```

Comment: But I need to save the punctuation mark on the array. @DeiDei

Comment: What do you need to do with `"It isn't true that Bill O'Reilly came in 3rd!"` as an input?  Splitting on spaces is fine; you'll need to think about also diagnosing substrings with, perhaps, [`strspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strspn.html) and [`strcspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html).  You're also going to have to copy material around because you can't simply add nulls after the words and before the trailing punctuation.

Comment: I would suggest not using `strtok`.  Just examine each character and take the appropriate action on each.

Comment: Please do not deface your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Now its work correctly and give me output:

```
[Hello] 
[,] 
[Sara] 
[!] 
[How] 
[are] 
[You] 
[?]
```

Don't forget to free array after using it, also you can save original string to assign pointer to tmp(for example) at begining of program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void skip_copied_bytes(char *str, int *i)
{
    char c = 0;
    while (*str == ' ' && str)
    {
        str++;
        (*i)++;
    }

    while (*str != ' ' && *str != '\0' && !ispunct(c))
    {
        str++;
        (*i)++;
        c = *str;
    }

    while (*str == ' ' && str)
    {
        str++;
        (*i)++;
    }
}

static int count_char(char *str)
{

    int count = 0;
    char c = 0;
    while (*str == ' ' && str)
        str++;


    while (*str != ' ' && *str != '\0' && !ispunct(c))
    {
        count++;
        str++;
        c = *str;
    }

    while (*str == ' ' && str)
    {
        str++;
    }

    return count;
}

static int count_word(char const *s, char c)
{
    int i;
    int count;

    count = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
        while (s[i] == c)
            i++;
        if (s[i] != '\0')
            count++;
        while (s[i] != c && s[i] != '\0') {
            if (ispunct(s[i]))
                count++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
int main(void)
{
    char *str = "Hello, Sara! How are You?";
    char **array;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int size = 0;

    size = count_word(str, ' ');
    if((array = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (size + 1))) == NULL)
        return -1;

    while (str[i])
    {
        size = count_char(&str[i]);
        if ((array[j] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size))) == NULL)
            return -1;

        strncpy(array[j], &str[i], size);
        array[j][size] = '\0';

        skip_copied_bytes(&str[i], &i);
        j++;
    }

    array[j] = 0;

    for(i = 0; array[i]; i++) {
        printf("[%s] \n", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea is that you can keep the original text and create a copy of it. While creating the copy, iterate each character of the text and check if the current character is any punctuation. If so, insert a space to the copy right before the punctuation and continue from the next character of the punctuation until reaching the terminating null character of the text. Finally, you can use `strtok()` to tokenize the text copy the same way as how you did. The following is the example implementing the above idea.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *stnc_org, *stnc_new;
    int size;
    printf("What is the expected size of the sentence: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    stnc_org = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));

    printf("Input: \n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", stnc_org);

    // get the number of punct
    int punct_num = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; *(stnc_org + i) != '\0'; i++) {
        if (ispunct(*(stnc_org + i))) {
            punct_num++;
        }
    }

    char * stnc_backup = (char *)malloc((size + punct_num * 2) * sizeof(char));
    stnc_new = stnc_backup;

    // copy the original str to the new and add space before each punct
    for (i = 0; *(stnc_org + i) != '\0'; i++) {
        if (ispunct(*(stnc_org + i))) { // found a punct
            // boundary check!!!
            // 1. the first character is the punct
            if (i == 0) {
                *(stnc_new + i) = *(stnc_org + i);
                *(stnc_new + i + 1) = ' ';
                stnc_new = stnc_new + (i + 2);
            } 
            // 2. the last character is the punct
            else if (*(stnc_org + i + 1) == '\0') {
                if (*(stnc_org + i - 1) != ' ') {
                    strncpy(stnc_new, stnc_org, i);
                    *(stnc_new + i) = ' ';
                    *(stnc_new + i + 1) = *(stnc_org + i);
                    *(stnc_new + i + 2) = '\0';
                    stnc_new = stnc_new + (i + 1);
                }
            }

            // check the previous and next characters of the punct
            // 3. previous not the space && next is space -> insert ' ' before the punct
            else if (*(stnc_org + i - 1) != ' ' && *(stnc_org + i + 1) == ' ') {
                strncpy(stnc_new, stnc_org, i);
                *(stnc_new + i) = ' ';
                *(stnc_new + i + 1) = *(stnc_org + i);
                stnc_new = stnc_new + (i + 1);
            }

            // 4. previous is space && next is not space -> insert ' ' after the punct
            else if (*(stnc_org + i - 1) == ' ' && *(stnc_org + i + 1) != ' ') {
                strncpy(stnc_new, stnc_org, i);
                *(stnc_new + i) = *(stnc_org + i);
                *(stnc_new + i + 1) = ' ';
                stnc_new = stnc_new + (i + 2);
            }

            // 5. no space before or after -> insert ' ' both before and after the punct
            else if (*(stnc_org + i - 1) != ' ' && *(stnc_org + i + 1) != ' ') {
                strncpy(stnc_new, stnc_org, i);
                *(stnc_new + i) = ' ';
                *(stnc_new + i + 1) = *(stnc_org + i);
                *(stnc_new + i + 2) = ' ';
                stnc_new = stnc_new + (i + 3);
            }

            // reset the pointer of the original text
            stnc_org = stnc_org + i + 1;
            // reset the index, so that it starts from 0 in the next loop
            i = -1;
        }
    }

    //printf("%s\n", stnc_backup);

    printf("\nOutput:\n");
    char *str;
    str = strtok(stnc_backup, " \n\r");

    while(str != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", str);
        str = strtok(NULL, " \n\r");
    }
}
```

The example output is as below:

```
Running "/home/ubuntu/workspace/replace.c"
What is the expected size of the sentence: 300
Input: 
"Isn't it true that Bill O'Reilly didn't win (he came in 3rd!)? 'Tain't necessarily so!"

Output:
"
Isn
'
t
it
true
that
Bill
O
'
Reilly
didn
'
t
win
(
he
came
in
3rd
!
)
?
'
Tain
'
t
necessarily
so
!
"


Process exited with code: 0
```

Comment: Note that a scan set is denoted by `%[…]` and is not a modifier of `%s`.  You have `scanf(" %[^\n]s", stnc_org);`.  The `%[^\n]` conversion is complete; the `s` is simply a literal letter, and the match always fails (because the character after the scan set is a newline — but in this context, you never get to know that the `s` match failed because there is no way for `scanf()` to report that failure.  You should test the result.  The leading space in the format string is entirely defensible and proper.

Comment: Your code compiles cleanly under stringent compilation options. That's good.  It produces the correct output on the sample data — that's good too.  There's some fun to be had with a string/line of input like: `Isn't it true that Bill O'Reilly didn't win (he came in 3rd!)? 'Tain't necessarily so!` — it doesn't break, but I'm intrigued that one of the words it produces is `'Tain`.  (If it's any consolation, my code isn't handling that either yet; an apostrophe at the beginning or end of the word is tricky.  But mine doesn't handle it differently.  I do handle apostrophes in words.)

Comment: The reason of that is I suppose that the punctuation is either followed by a space or the terminating null character. So, in case of, for example, ```(he came...```, since the punctuation is followed by a word, what my code does (i.e., inserting a space before the punctuation) will not help. In order to solve this problem, we need to consider several cases:

Comment: 1. punctuation is the first character of the text (e.g., ```"hello"```; 2. punctuation is followed by either a space or the terminating null character (e.g., ```hello, world!```); 3. punctuation is after a space, and followed by a word (e.g., ```hello (world).```); 4. no space is before or after the punctuation (e.g., ```It's```). Once the code covers every case, it should work.

Comment: The new code seems to work well — like the old code did.  It was very much a corner case that I was pointing out.  I can't up-vote twice, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: That's fine. Good discussion though. Thanks.